# How to add hyperlink to array format in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a hyperlink by put that url info to data array.
But the anchor tag with href does not work as I thought.

Should I use react-router-dom's Link tag? Or would there be any clue to add hyperlink when I add {link} on Goods.js?

#1 Shop.js

```
export const Shop = () => {
  return (
    <div className="shop">
      <div className="shop-title">
        <h1>Anime Biased Shop</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="items">
        {ItemsList.map((item) => (
          <Goods shopItemProps={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#2 Goods.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Goods = (props) => {
  const { id, name, price, image, link } = props.shopItemProps;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="goods">
        <div>{id}</div>
        <img src={image} alt="thumbnail_image" />
        <div className="goods-name">{name}</div>
        <div className="goods-price">${price}</div>
        <a href={link} />
        <div className="cart-button">
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
          {count}
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

#3 ItemsList.js (the data array file I mentioned)

```
export const ItemsList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "VA-11 Hall-A: Cyberpunk Bartender Action",
    price: 110000,
    image: cover1,
    link: "https://store.steampowered.com/app/447530/VA11_HallA_Cyberpunk_Bartender_Action/?l=koreana",
  },
```

Comment: why does it not work as you thought? Your code is fine currently so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: An anchor tag should be used as `<a href={link}>content</a>`, not `<a href={link} />`

Comment: ...you were right. Guess I need to take some break. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

### 1. External links or redirect with page refresh

If it is external link, to other website you should use `a`. This looks nice

```
        <a href={link} />
```

but can be not visible, because you do not have any content in this link. You can change it to:

```
        <a href={link}><button>Click me</button></a>
```

### 2. Internal links without page reload

If it is internal link, you should remove domain, eg by `replace` function and use `Link` if you using `next`

```
        <Link href="/about">About Us</Link>
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

or `Redirect` if you using `react-router-dom`

```
   <Redirect to='/profile' />
```

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/programmatically-navigate-with-react-router

In both cases you should add something inside of this element or add classes that make id visible.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Test `<a href="#">click me</a>`

or React Router Dom like this :

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "john",
    profile: "/profile",
    linkTo: "/user/john",
  },
];

{
  data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Link to={item.linkTo}>
        <h1>name:{item.name}</h1>
        <Link to={item.profile}>
          <h5>editProfile</h5>
        </Link>
      </Link>
    );
  });
}
```